# $2^x-x^2+x+\cos(x)=0$ has one real root

Tags: calculus, functions

We just need to show that $2^x-x^2+x+\cos(x)=0$ has exactly one real root.

How I approached it :

Let $f(x)=2^x-x^2+x+\cos(x)$

$f$ is differentiable with $f'(x)=\log2 \cdot 2^x -2x +1 - \sin(x)$

We can see that for $x \in (-\infty,0) , f'(x) \gt 0 \implies f$ is always increasing . Now we can find the range of $f$ for $x<0$ and it turns out to be $f((-\infty ,0))=(-\infty , 2)$ .

So $f$ has exactly one root for $x<0$

But this is how far I've come so far . For possitive $x$ I cannot seem to figure out how to work it out. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: @AdamRubinson Yes! thank you for pointing it out I must have miss-typed it

Comment: Is it enough to show that there is at least one real root or must it be shown that there is exactly one real root ? In the first case , it is enough to find a negative and a positive value.

Comment: @Peter No , we need to show that there is exactly one .

Comment: I asked chatGPT to prove it, but it lacked any details, and just said to analyse $f'(x),$ which is not very helpful.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Surprising enough that ChatGPT noticed that this is the way to do it. Chapeau :)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't manage to solve this problem but here is how i reasoned for the case $x\geq0$.(Also i'm not really sure on how to formalize the last part)
I found out that in $(0,1)$ the function is decreasing  because:
$$x\in(0,1)\Rightarrow f'(x)\approx -2^x(\frac{log^2(2)}{3})-2x+1$$
and when we ask it to be greater than 0 we have
$$2^x(\frac{log^2(2)}{3})+2x\leq-1.$$ Which is never satisfied. for $x>1$ I realized that there must be an absolute minimum considering that the function it's nonnegative and decreasing in $[0,1]$ but $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=+\infty$. The value of $f'(3)$ is positive, so the minimum is in $[1,3]$. We might find an absurd through the Rolle's theorem.
For example let's assume that $x_0$ is a positive root of $f$ and is also the minimum, if there where another positve root $x_1$ by Rolle's theorem we should have a point $x_2\in[x_0,x_1]$ (assuming WLOG $x_1\geq x_0$) such that $f'(x_2)=0$ but we know that $f$ is nonnegative in $[0,+\infty)$ so $x_2$ is a local maximum of $f$. Which would mean that the convexity of $f$ changed twice in such a small interval which is not really the case for the structure of this function. So, if there is a root, it's unique. 
It's now reasonable to assume that if such a root exists it must be a minimum for $f$, so let's put $$f(x)=2^x-x^2+x+\cos{x}= 0 (\star) \\f'(x)=\log{2}2^x-2x+1-\sin{x}=0 (\star\star).$$ ,
From $(\star)$ we get $$2^x=x^2-x-\cos{x} \\ (\star\star)\Rightarrow \log{2}(x^2-x-\cos{x})=2x-1+\sin{x}\\\log{2}=\frac{2x-1+\sin{x}}{x^2-x-\cos{x}}.$$ Now let's integrate this and put the constant of integration equal to $2$ since we need to find a contradiction in at least one spot.
$$\int\log{2}\,dx=\int\frac{2x-1+\sin{x}}{x^2-x-\cos{x}}\,dx\\
x\log{2}+2=\log{x^2-x-\cos{x}}\Rightarrow e^2 x =x^2-x-\cos{x}$$
By taking the logarithm and using $(\star)$ we get:
$$\log{(e^2x)}=\log(2^x)\Rightarrow x=e^2$$
Which would mean that for that value of $x$ we have a root of $f$ but in $[3,+\infty)$ $f$ is never $0$

Comment: That is helpful I'll take your idea and see where I can go with it ! Thanks for the help.